# Bootstrap. Как свернуть меню в гамбургер при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Есть адаптивное меню на bootstrap. 
Задача - при скролле вниз меню должно свернуться в "гамбургер" (либо остаться без изменений, в зависимости от ширины экрана). При скролле вверх соответственно - снова развернуться.
Приблизительно как это реализовано с левым меню на сайте dns-shop.ru
Есть ли у кого то практика в таком вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Обрабатываешь событие скрола, в нём прячешь бургер

```
document.getElementById("wrapperID").addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      document.getElementById("burgerID").style.display = "none";
    })
```

Comment: Дело в том, что "сворачивание" бургера в бутстрапе зависит от ширины экрана, как это сделать вручную - не понятно